# Searching within digits using Java

Tags: java, numbers, digits

Hi I have a text file containing some 2-digit integer numbers. I want to find if any of the two digit numbers contain specific single digit numbers. An example number is 12 in the text file. I want to test if there is a 1 or 3 in these number's digits:

```
package algoritmahomework3;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class AlgoritmaHomework3 {

    private static BufferedReader br = null;
    private static String[] split;
    private static String fileName = "input.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try {
            // txt String variable is putting the file's content here.
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Alparslan\\Desktop\\input.txt"));
            String txt = " ";
            String msg = " ";
            while((msg = br.readLine()) != null){
                txt += msg;
            }
            for(int i=0; i<txt.length(); i++){
                split = txt.split(" ");
                // split is a static array to put inside the splitted data which is in txt file.
                // This succeed. You can test it using below line of code.
                //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
            }
            printGraph(txt);
           } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AlgoritmaHomework3.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
      }
    private static void printGraph(java.lang.String txt) {
        if(Integer.parseInt(txt)==1){

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: I have numbers in text file. for example 12. This has 2 digits. 1 and 2. I want to find if 1 is one of that digits or not

Comment: str.indexOf('1')!=-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the numbers:

```
String numberStr = yourStr.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

if you want to keep decimal point use:

```
yourStr.replaceAll("[^\\.0123456789]","");
```

then you can check for individual numbers.

To add space between numbers:

```
String numberStr = yourStr.replaceAll("[^0-9]", " ");
```

To get only the numbers, and store them to a string array:

```
String arr[] = s1.trim().split("[a-zA-Z ]+"); // Please note a space is there after Z
```

Then store all numbers into integer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    no = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
    System.out.println(no);
}
```

Comment: Thanks what I wanted is this. :D

Comment: see this might help: http://www.nataraz.in/how-to-get-only-numbers-from-alphanumeric-string/#

Answer (score 0):

If you have the two digits as string, such as "12" you can test if it contains another string by using the `.indexOf` method.

```
String s = "12";
if (s.indexOf("1") != -1) {
  // it contains "1"
}

if (s.indexOf("2") != -1) {
  // it contains "2"
}
```